# Why one add calcuation in C/RUST has 3 double-precision floating-point add instruments in result ASM?

Tags: c, assembly, rust, simd, auto-vectorization

Simple C code, only one double-precision adding.

```
void test(double *a, double *b, long n) {
    for (long j = 0; j < n; j++)
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = b[i] + a[j];
    }
}
```

Get ASM result in compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/tJ-d39

There are one `addpd` and two `addsd`. Both are double-precision related.

Another similar rust code, got even more double-precision adding instruments: https://godbolt.org/z/c49Wuh

```
pub unsafe fn test(a: &mut [f64], b: &mut [f64], n: usize) {
    for j in 0..n {
        for i in 0..n {
            *b.get_unchecked_mut(i) = *b.get_unchecked_mut(i) + *a.get_unchecked_mut(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this code can be written much more easily

Comment: What is your actual question. You're comparing different languages (with different compiler btw (gcc vs LLVM/clang)). Please clarify your question, so it can be answered.

Comment: @hellow I was rewrite C version linpack benchmark to Rust. The benchmark mainly measure double-precision calculation in big array. Rust version got about 50% performance of C version. I double check compile optimization options. Remove Slice index boundary check  with unsafe code. Performance gap is still big. So I want to know the difference in assembly view.

Comment: You cannot expect different compilers to yield the same code. Moreover, that Rust code is extremely dangerous and unidiomatic. Rewriting in Rust should mean to avoid the safety problems of C. [This version](https://godbolt.org/z/QDLF4W) would be a bit better.

Comment: This Rust code is much more idiomatic and does the same thing: https://godbolt.org/z/L32qQ8  `a` doesn't have to be mutable, BTW

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [compiling without optimizations](https://godbolt.org/z/IYXPXz) and you will get only one `addsd` instruction. The two extra additions in the C code are due to auto-vectorization. In particular if you look at lines 34 and 37 of the disassembly, you will see vector memory accesses. The `addpd` is the main addition for the vectorized code and the two `addsd`s are there to handle boundary conditions.

The extra instructions in the Rust code are due to loop unrolling.

As pointed out by @Peter Cordes, gcc doesn't do loop unrolling by default at `-O3` optimization, whereas LLVM (on which the Rust compiler is based) does. Hence the difference between the C code and the Rust code.

Comment: GCC doesn't do loop unrolling by default at `-O3`. `-funroll-loops` is enabled as part of `-fprofile-use`, or can be enabled manually.  Clang/LLVM does loop unrolling. The normal Rust compiler is based on LLVM which *does* unroll tiny/small loops by a factor of 4 or 2, or more depending on tune options, so that's what the OP is seeing with Rust, but it's *not* happening in the code you're talking about. (GCC will still *fully* unroll some loops when the trip count is a small constant number of iterations.  Especially if constant-propagation across iterations can greatly simplify the loop body)

Comment: A much better suggestion than `-O0` for simple asm here would be `gcc -O2`, or `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize`.  (Note that clang enables auto-vectorization even at `-O2`, but gcc doesn't.)  With clang you can also use `-fno-unroll-loops`.  `-O0` is a horrible mess that's hard to read because it doesn't keep anything in registers between statements.  Anyway, using `-fno-tree-vectorize` shows that the extra instructions are coming from vectorization, not other optimizations.

Answer (score 6):

In your GCC output from C++, the first 2 are from auto-vectorization with `addpd` (Packed Double) + scalar cleanup with `addsd` (Scalar Double).  If you wanted to compile it as C, use `-xc` in the compiler options.

The extra `addsd` at the bottom is in a separate pure-scalar loop for the case where the input arrays overlap.

---

The two scalar `addsd` instructions are necessary because you haven't promised the compiler that the input arrays don't overlap (with `double *restrict a`), and you haven't promised that the size is an even number of `double`s.

So to auto-vectorize with SIMD, we need to check for overlap.  And we need cleanup in case the length isn't a whole number of SIMD vectors.

This is also why there are so many integer instructions in the function, instead of just 2 simple nested loops.

Your Rust/LLVM output is the same, but with loop-unrolling (which LLVM does by default) for the main SIMD loop.  So the scalar cleanup loop may need to run more than 1 iteration, because 1 SIMD loop iteration does more than just 2 elements.

---

Unfortunately GCC/clang don't optimize your function to sum up `a[0..n-1]` and then loop over `b` once, adding the total to each element.  That would be legal with `-ffast-math` (otherwise not because FP math isn't strictly associative), but unfortunately compilers don't do it anyway.  You'd have to do it yourself in the source.

That's a major missed optimization, going from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` complexity.  But it's one that compilers won't do for you, even with `-ffast-math`.